# WPF как правильно организовать структуру бд и DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, xaml, проектирование

Есть DataGrid, нужно реализовать возможность обеденения ячейек

1. Как сделать выделение мышкой нескольких ячеек (не строк!)
2. Как понять какие ячейки выделены ведь потом нужно занести запись в бд
3. Как при запуске программы на основе записей в бд сделать обеденение ячеек
4. Как правильно организовать поля бд в таблице

Должно получиться что-то подобное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, вы смешали всё в кучу, об этом даже количество меток говорит. В 95% случаев вам не должно хотеться поставить более двух-трех меток. Разделите вопрос на несколько и задайте отдельно.

Comment: И да, ответом на первые 3 вопроса будет - НИКАК. Штатный DataGrid этого не умеет, ищите либо сторонний контрол или пишите свой. Можно попробовать кастомизировать, конечно, и штатный DataGrid, но в него придется напихать столько всего, что проще отказаться от него вообще и собрать нужное из более простых элементов

Comment: @Андрей можете подсказать сторонние контролы для этого?

Comment: Смотрите, какой-нибудь DevExpress, например: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6084/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid Или Telerik: https://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid вроде сам не умеют, придется ручками.

1,2.

Отлавливать выделение ячейки и переход от одной к другой можно(гугл). Сделайте так, чтобы при выделении ячейки с Ctrl запоминалась ячейки до перехода и перекрашивалась в цвет выделения. Внутри программы делаем массив выделенных ячеек.

3.

Подробнее

4.

Нужна ваша схема БД для начала.

P.S. Опишите конкретнее проблему(задачу) и разделите на под вопросы.
P.S.S. Как и советовали в комментариях - такая задача должна быть у многих(стандартные функции), поэтому наверняка есть готовые элементы с таким функционалом. Ищите.